# Continuous random variable transformations

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $Y$ be a continuous random variable with $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2}(1+y).$  Define $W_1=-4Y+7$.  Find $f_{W_i}.$

I'm just checking the following solution:

$F_{W_1}(w)=P(W\leq w)=P(-4Y+7\leq w)=P\left(\frac{7-w}{4}\leq Y\right)=F_Y\left(\frac{7-w}{4}\right)=\frac{-1}{4}f_Y\left(\frac{7-w}{4}\right)=\frac{-1}{4}[\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{7-w}{4})]=\frac{-1}{32}(11-w).$

This is nonzero between $11\leq w \leq 3$

Comment: I don't understand the step $F_Y\left(\frac{7-w}{4}\right)=\frac{-1}{4}f_Y\left(\frac{7-w}{4}\right)$. You are supposed to compute $F_Y()$ instead and replace

Comment: abet means, $F_W(w) = \mathsf P(Y\geq \tfrac 1 4(7-w)) = 1- F_Y(\tfrac{1}{4}(7-w)) \\ \implies f_W(w) = -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d y}f_Y(\tfrac{1}{4}(7-w)) = \tfrac 1 4 f_Y(\tfrac{1}{4}(7-w))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the support for $f_y$ is $[-1,1]$, then you are *nearly* correct:

$$\begin{align}
F_W(w) & = \mathsf P(7-4Y\leq w)
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(Y\geq \tfrac 1 4(7-w))
\\[1ex] & = 1- F_Y(\tfrac{1}{4}(7-w)) 
\\[2ex] \implies f_W(w) & = -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d y}f_Y(\tfrac{1}{4}(7-w))
\end{align}$$

However, you don't need to involve the cumulative density function at all. Just transform the density function, via:

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \tfrac 1 2(1+y)\quad\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y)
\\[2ex]
 w & = 7-4y
\\[2ex]\therefore
f_W(w) & = f_Y(\tfrac 1 4(7-w))\cdot\left|\frac{\mathrm d \tfrac 1 4(7-w)}{\mathrm d w}\right|
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 2(1+\tfrac 1 4(7-w))\cdot \tfrac{1}{4}\quad\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(\tfrac 1 4(7-w))
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 {32}(11-w)\quad\mathbf 1_{[3,11]}(w)
\end{align}$$

**Notice:** The transformation multiplied by the *absolute value* of the derivative to ensure that the probability density is always positive over the support.